# Serialize form to pass to ASP.Net web API

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Before I go off and recreate the wheel, can anyone tell me if there's a way to do this automatically? I have a view model which contains an array of another object type, a bit like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ChildViewModel[] Children { get; set; } 
}


public class ChildViewModel {
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Severity { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling a web api function that takes a ParentViewModel as a parameter:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Test([FromBody]ParentViewModel vm) {
    }
```

This is called from a web page which can have a dynamic number of child entities. The page is created using asp.net/Razor, so these are bound to input fields with HTML like this:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" class="form-control" id="Children_0__Description" name="Children[0].Description" value="test" type="text">
```

I have a javascript event handler that uses ajax to call the web api. I want to pass the form data to it, so I serialise the form, use deparam to turn it into an object, and call JSON.stringify on the object. Unfortunately this doesn't turn stuff like "Children[0].Description into an array of objects for me, so when it hits the web api it doesn't get mapped to the array property of the view model. Ie, my JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "ID": "12",
    "Children[0].Severity" : "3",
    "Children[0].Description" : "Test", 
    "Children[1].Severity" : "5",
    "Children[1].Description" : "Another",
    "Title": "Hello"
}
```

Instead of like this:

```
{
    "ID": "12",
    "Children" : [
        {"Severity":"3", "Description":"Test"},
        {"Severity":"5", "Description":"Another"},
        ],
    "Title": "Hello"
}
```

I was about to write some code to transform the json, but I'm guessing I'm either doing something wrong in the first place, or there's already something that will do this for me - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but I've solved the problem (nothing like describing your problem to others to crystallise your thinking). The problem was that deparam wasn't the best library to use. Instead I found [this](https://github.com/raphaelm22/jquery.serializeToJSON) library that does precisely what I need.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465156/web-api-not-deserializing-properties-of-child-array-in-post) has same problem as yours. If yes you need to add contenttype in your ajax call header.

Comment: Thanks Shashank. Sounds similiar, but in my case I already have the contentType attribute in place